# Is it possible to disallow the closing of an android app?

Tags: java, android, security

For an app I'm creating, I need a lock screen. For security purposes, the user shouldn't be able to access the app tray or the home button while in this lock screen.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: If you have your own version of Android then you can do this, otherwise it would be a risk to allow this to happen, so no, you can't.  You can't take over the home button.

Comment: If you could explain the use case there may be a better solution that will work.

Comment: @JamesBlack You can take over the Home button. That's what launchers do but the users can override/change this via set defaults screen.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Launchers don't exactly take over the home button.  They register to receive the intent it broadcasts.  If another app is registered for the same intent, the user will be asked to choose which app receives it.

Comment: @JamesBlack Yes, that's the process but with launchers and lock screen type apps the users would make your app the default right away unless say they are testing between a couple of launchers to see which one they like. What I'm saying is once the default is set.. the app will respond to home button presses. If you were saying *you  can't take over the home button... without user's consent* then yes that's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible using the new [task pinning API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) in Lollipop.  And if your app is not the device owner, the user will be asked for permission every time you try to engage the lock.  On a non-rooted device, the device owner can only be set up during the initial provisioning after a factory reset.